# Java's SHA1 deprecation plan

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, sha

Microsoft ceases to trust code signing certificate that use SHA-1 from January 2016 (https://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/SHA-2-transition.php). I am not able to find any such reference or deprecation policy for SHA-1 for Java. If anyone can provide relevant pointers that would be helpful.

Comment: I haven't seen a statement on when *they* will do it, but several years ago they exposed a configurable setting 
that allows *you* to do it whenever you like; see "Cert Path Algorithm Disabling" in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html

Comment: Thanks, good to know one can disable supporting algorithms as per configuration. But, wanted this information to check how long the jars which are already signed with SHA-1 certificate will be supported to run on default configuration.